# Understanding BCryptSignHash output signature

Tags: linux, cryptoapi, ecdsa, cng

I have signed a hash value in windows using *BCryptSignHash* with ECDSA algorithm. The output signature buffer is of length 64 bytes. I also generated the public and private key blobs using *BCryptGenerateKeyPair* function (BCRYPT_ECDSA_P256_ALGORITHM algorithm) with which i signed the hash.

I have to verify this signature with this key pair in linux. I am able to decipher the public-private key pair that got generated, using the link "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx" and able to use the same in linux.

The 64-byte signature generated should ideally be signature pair (r,s) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_DSA).

Is there a way to understand the 64-bytes signature generated so that i can map the signature blob contents to (r,s) pair in linux and verify it?

Or is there a simpler way to verify the generated signature in linux?

Thanks,
F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to understand the 64-bytes signature generated so that I can map the signature blob contents to (r,s) pair in linux and verify it?

The `r` and `s` are in P1363 format, which is simply a concatenation of `r` and `s` in a 2's compliment format. That is, the signature is simply `r || s`.

You need to know the hash to use this format. For example, SHA1 will create a `r` of 20 bytes and an `s` of 20 bytes. If `r` or `s` is "too short", then it is padded on the left with 0's.

Java and OpenPGP are different than P1363. Java and OpenPGP use an ASN.1 encoding:

```
SEQUENCE ::= {
  r INTEGER,
  s INTEGER
}
```

Depending what library you use on Linux, you may have to convert between the formats. [Cryptographic Interoperability: Digital Signatures](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25590/Cryptographic-Interoperability-Digital-Signatures) gives examples of signing and verifying using a few different libraries.

---

> Or is there a simpler way to verify the generated signature in linux?

Try [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com). I believe Microsoft and Crypto++ uses the same signature format, so you won't need to convert. See [Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. I tried crypto++ and i was able to use the signature and keys in both windows and linux application levels.

But now i got an another problem to deal with...|

Signing is being done in windows application level. Verification has to be done in 2 places - linux application & in windows driver. Crypto++ was useful in creating keys in windows application level and with it i signed the data. Using the same key, i was able to verify data in linux application. Now the problem i have is i cant use crypto++ in windows drivers.

Is there a common library available across 3 formats?